# Swift refresh tableview cell data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using tableview to show some data from json. I am using an array of object to populate those data. Now I want to refresh those data after a certain time(e.g. 10 sec) like yahoo cricket mobile app. Can any one please suggest me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using timers is one way you can do it, In `ViewDidload`

```
   self.myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: "refresh", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    func refresh() {
        tableview.reloadData(); //refresh the table
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a timer which run for every 10 sec as

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selectior(refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func refresh() {
    // fetch Data from Server
}
```

After fetching the data, populate your array again and use tableView method `reloadData` to reload the tableView

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

To update some rows of the data you can use code below. Here I'm demonstrating one row update, you can do the same with multiple row update by passing as many as `indexPath` in an array you want

```
//suppose you want to update row 0 for section 0, create indexPath as
let indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
tableview.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath1], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

If you want to update your particular section, do this

```
//suppose you want to update your section 0
let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 0)
profileTableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. Actually I am using node.js and socket for auto update . Now I want to swap some rows with other rows and update data. How can I do that? Basically I need some thing like "wechat" friend section. Where the friends name get updated according to their location.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to use an NSTimer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer : NSTimer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selectior(fetch), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func fetch() {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```